# VS2010 won't open files

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have VS2010 C# Express installed, and it was working just fine. However, as of today, none of the menus seem to open the Explorer menus.

For example, I was working with an XNA project when I first noticed it, I went to add an existing file to my project, and when I clicked the option in the context menu ... nothing. After poking around a bit, I noticed that I can't even click the open file button or Ctrl-O. I can confirm it's only VS that is affected, all my other programs work just fine.

Now, I have tried to repair the installation for it, and failing that, I did a complete uninstall, followed by a reinstall, but no luck. I also tried the Professional version and had the same results.

EDIT: Now, a few days later, it seems to be working just fine. I don't know what caused it, but I know my HDD might be slowly failing, but I wouldn't think the two are related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the resolution was to run it in Compatibility Mode.